# I need help sending Android code coverage using github Action to Codecov

Tags: android-studio, code-coverage, github-actions, codecov

I am trying to send my Unit test code coverage to Codecov using Github action but it is not working and showing me the below response.
this is the response I have been getting since
[image: Github action response]

[image: Response i get in Codecov platform]

Answer (score 0):

Tom from Codecov here, it looks like you got this working, but it seems like the file you are specifying isn't in that location. It could either not be correct based on your working directory, or you could be mistaken with where it's located. There are two things we recommend

1. You could have a step prior to the Codecov action that checks if the file exists (e.g. `ls app/build/reports/coverage/debug/index.html`)
2. You could remove the file to see what Codecov automatically picks up. Note that I don't think we accept html as a valid coverage report.

Comment: I have tried so many solutions that didn't work, please what type of code coverage file format I can send from an Android project

Comment: @wise4rmgod we have an example repository [here](https://github.com/codecov/example-android)

Comment: the example you sent is for Travis and not for Github Action